# blank csv file after scrapping using python jupyter

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

data=[]
page= requests.get("https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-6627930/bukan-gegara-lab-bocor-ilmuwan-sebut-asal-usul-corona-dari-rakun-di-pasar-wuhan")
soup= BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
judul= soup.find("h1",class_="detail__title").text
penulis= soup.find("div",class_="detail__author").text
isi= soup.find("div",class_="detail__body-text itp_bodycontent").text

print(judul)
print(penulis)
print(isi)

data.append({
        "judul": judul,
        "penulis": penulis,
        "isi": isi
        })

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("pppp.csv",index=False,encoding="utf-8")
```

I ran the code to scrape the web using Jupyter. However, while the code did not return any error and the csv output exists in my folder, the cell is empty. I ran the same code as my friend of which the result was not empty and give valuable information.

Please help, thank you.

I expect the result to follow the code but unfortunately it does not give the same result as I expected

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with the code per se - Please take a closer look to the response / `soup` to ensure you work on your expected elements, it may also contains more information to debug, maybe you are blocked and have to set user-agent.

Comment: Check if the csv file is open in your MS Excel etc. It may be blocking write to csv.

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

data=[]
page= requests.get("https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-6627930/bukan-gegara-lab-bocor-ilmuwan-sebut-asal-usul-corona-dari-rakun-di-pasar-wuhan")
soup= BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
judul= soup.find("h1",class_="detail__title").text
penulis= soup.find("div",class_="detail__author").text
isi= soup.find("div",class_="detail__body-text itp_bodycontent").text

print(judul)
print(penulis)
print(isi)

data.append({
    "judul": judul.strip().replace("\n", ' '),
    "penulis": penulis.strip().replace("\n", ' '),
    "isi": isi.strip().replace("\n", ' ')
    })

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("pppp.csv",index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain what removing the encoding does to the solution that the content is displayed in the CSV?

Comment: I think you are not getting the empty value, The cell looks like empty because of empty lines in the string. Can you please try the above code and let me know